# Finding correct format for PHP comments in Doxygen

Tags: php, doxygen, phpdoc

**Which is the correct doxygen format for PHP comments?**

## #1

```
/** Create HTML for tags
 * @param string @tags
 */
```

## #2

```
   /** 
     * Create HTML for tags
     * @param string @tags
     */
```

## #3

```
   /**! Create HTML for tags
     * @param string @tags
     */
```

Comment: Koning: At least one of them such that I can get started. - I know how to make scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All should work.

Comment: This suggests me that the problem is somewhere else, since I get no output in the generated LaTeX and HTML files in running Doxygen by Doxywizard.

Comment: The main problem is to be able to rerun Doxygen. I opened a new thread about this problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354022/rerunning-doxygen-guis-convertion-in-ubuntu